# C# SQLBULKCOPY import massive text file to one column, to a specific row

Tags: c#, sql

Does anybody have a an example of how to import a huge textfile to a specific row using SQLBULKCOPY and streamreader?  Basically need to put all of the text file into one column in a specific row that has a value i am looking for.

Comment: okay so SQLBULKCOPY can't do this, what do I need to do in order to actually get a good performance

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL file-stream support in 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure sqlbulkcopy is the best tool for that. I would look at he BLOB writing TSQL commands via regular SqlCommand (usually in a loop). However I also wonder at the wisdom of storing a huge BLOB in the db when an external file may be preferable an simpler.

Comment: okay so how do i inject a 1.8million line file into a specific row that wont take 2 days to finish?

Comment: @mike if it is just a blob, then read in chunks of some decent multiple of 8040 - maybe 100*8040, and Append that each time. The TSQL is different between image text ntext varbinary max varchar max etc. But each has an append

Comment: @mike - additionally; what *good* is this as a blob? IMO either transform it into structured data ( where you *can* use SqlBulkCopy), or leave it outside the db (and just store the path in the db)